# python 3 exception also gives the output of the previous program

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

i ran into an interesting bug when writing a json parser(called /home/myusername/py/json.py) in python3
i raised a basic exception and got unexpected output,

when investigating this further i wrote a new script entirely given below

## /home/myusername/py/error.py

```
raise Exception("basic exception")
```

after running "python3 error.py"
i should get a really short error message, but instead i get console output of  the previous run program.

```
[unexpected debug output of json.py]
[truncated for readability]
[it is extremely long but does not contain further errors]

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "error.py", line 1, in <module>
raise Exception("basic exception")
Exception: basic exception
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 17, in <module>
    import json
  File "/home/myusername/py/json.py", line 174, in <module>
    rs = parser.Object(testcase)
  File "/home/myusername/py/json.py", line 104, in Object
    raise Exception(self.Array(source, "crashing object scanner"))
Exception: None

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise Exception("basic exception")
Exception: basic exception
```

i dont know why i get such a long message. nor do i know why i get debug code of an uncalled script. i would like an explanation, i am running Ubuntu, i have not yet found related bugs on the internet.

Comment: The error traces back multiple files, check the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Why should i get any output from json.py if i run error.py and error.py makes no reference to json.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that basic exception handling requires a json.py script, so when my error.py raises an exception it loads my json.py script instead of the buildin script, then my json script trows an exception.

the solution is to rename my json.py